# pandas speed up multi-row calculation by using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to make a calculation on multiple rows for every row in a dataframe.

My current solution takes almost 2 hours for 200k rows. so it's pretty inefficient, I'm hoping groupby or some other pandas methods can help me here.

my data looks like this for example (you can ignore the dates for now):

```
id group start_date end_date   three_yrs_ago_date days_missing
01 23    2005-01-01 2006-01-01 2002-01-01           1
02 23    2006-01-06 2007-01-06 2003-01-06           6
03 23    2007-01-15 2008-01-15 2004-01-15           9
07 17    2014-01-01 2015-02-01 2011-01-01           2
07 23    2015-01-01 2016-02-01 2012-01-01           4
```

so the goal here is to group everything by its `group` number and then add up all the `days_missing` of all the other rows in that group that occurred within the last 3 years. That is to say the other rows `start_date` is at or after the current row's `three_yrs_ago_date`, and at or before the current row's `end_date`.

That's a mouthful, but its basically three criteria. so that if this were the whole dataset we'd get this result (dropping the date columns):

```
id group days_missing days_missing_in_last_three_years            
01 23    1            1    # no change: no prior years
02 23    6            7 
03 23    9            16  
07 17    2            2    # no change: only member of it's group
07 23    4            4    # no change: other group members more than 3 years ago
```

I'll show you the code I currently have, but it's slow.

I go through the dataframe row by row, creating a temporary dataframe containing all it's group members, then I whittle those group members down to only the ones within the date criteria. It's not pretty:

```
days=[]
for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows()):
    # moderately slow (~2 hour):
    temp = df[df['group'] == row['group']]
    temp = temp[temp['start_date'] >= row['three_yrs_ago_date']]
    temp = temp[temp['end_date'] <= row['start_date']]
    add = temp['days_missing'].sum() + row['days_missing']
    days.append(add)
df['days_missing_in_last_three_years'] = days
```

I tried 2 other approaches but neither was successful:

```
# very slow (~3 hours):
cov.append(df[(df['group'] == row['group']) & (df['start_date'] >= row['three_yrs_ago_date']) & (df['end_date'] <= row['start_date'])]['days_missing'].sum()+row['days_missing'])

# doesn't work - incorrect use of groupby
df['test'] = df[(df.groupby(['group'])['start_date'] >= df.groupby(['group'])['three_yrs_ago_date']) & (df.groupby(['group'])['end_date'] <= df.groupby(['group'])['start_date'])]['days_missing'].sum()
```

Is there a better way to do this more efficiently than breaking it up into smaller temporary dataframes and doing calculations on them?

Comment: just a comment, 'days_missing' is 0 or 1 for the first row? (you used 0 the first time and 1 the second tine)

Comment: Yes. There is definitely a better way to do this than breaking it up into smaller data frames. Do you know anything about Big O? Also, you can also look into latency profiling (cProfile). For this specific issue, I'll defer to others but if you can get the groupby done first you should be able to do some simple element based computations.

Comment: Also, @Legit Stack, if you need to iterate over a DF, itertuples is much faster than iterrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one solution, probably faster than your way. use a loop `for` on df.groupby('group'), then `apply` on each grouped datagrame `df_g`. You can use the method between to select the part of `df_g` betweem both dates for each row

```
for name, df_g in df.groupby('group'):
    df.loc[df_g.index,'test'] = df_g.apply(lambda row: (df_g['days_missing'][df_g['start_date']
                                                           .between(row['three_yrs_ago_date'], row['end_date'])].sum()),1)
df['test'] = df['test'].astype(int) #to get integer
```

the result is like expected:

```
   id  group start_date   end_date three_yrs_ago_date  days_missing  test
0   1     23 2005-01-01 2006-01-01         2002-01-01             1     1
1   2     23 2006-01-06 2007-01-06         2003-01-06             6     7
2   3     23 2007-01-15 2008-01-15         2004-01-15             9    16
3   7     17 2014-01-01 2015-02-01         2011-01-01             2     2
4   7     23 2015-01-01 2016-02-01         2012-01-01             4     4
```

EDIT: faster way by using `numpy` function:

```
import numpy as np
for name, df_g in df.groupby('group'):
    m_g = ( np.less_equal.outer(df_g['three_yrs_ago_date'], df_g['start_date']) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(df_g['end_date'], df_g['start_date']) )
    df.loc[df_g.index,'test'] =np.dot(m_g, df_g['days_missing'])
df['test'] = df['test'].astype(int) #to get integer
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I fixed the issue you found in the question too. This works great. I've used apply elsewhere didn't think about it for this problem. and it cut my run time from like 2 hours to like 10 minutes!

Comment: @LegitStack I added another solution, it's probably faster!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt using `.groupby`, `.loc` and `.transform`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = (
    (df['start_date'] >= df['three_yrs_ago_date'])
    & (df['end_date'] <= df['start_date'])
)
df['test'] = np.nan # initiliaze column, otherwise next line raises KeyError
df.loc[conditions, 'test'] = df.loc[conditions, ].groupby('group')['days_missing'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: This solution runs fast and looks elegant but I can't get it to work, my 'test' column stays nan. I'd like to get this to work, because it looks awesome and I like the look of the pattern, but one of the other answers works for me so I probably wont spend anymore time on this, thanks!